# Multiple Category select Layered Navigation in magento 1.9

Tags: filter, magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I want to Enabled Multiple Category select in Layered Navigation.

E.g: i have category

1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Orange

If click on apple category display filter option like:

1. **Apple**
2. Banana
3. Orange